# Average of an array (struct)

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, average

I've been going at this and can't seem to find the right way to do it. I only left the code that works because the rest is just embarrassing...

*Create a program using 2 arrays that holds a class set of data for 10 students:
The first array holds the first and last name (in different cells) of the students
The second array holds the grades (5 total) for each of the students
Create appropriate functions to load and display the array including the average 
and letter grade of the student. Drop the lowest grade from the student's average.*

I'm not asking for someone to do it for me, I just would like some help.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int CLASSIZE = 1;

struct student
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

    void printTheInfo()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName;
    }
    void loadMe()
    {
        cout << "First Name: ";
        cin >> firstName;
        cout << "Last Name: ";
        cin >> lastName;
    }
};
struct grades
{
    int grade1;
    int grade2;
    int grade3;
    int grade4;
    int grade5;

    void printTheGrades()
    {
        cout << " Grades: " << grade1 << " " << grade2 << " " << grade3
             << " " << grade4 << " " << grade5 << endl;
    }
    void loadGrades()
    {
        cout << "Grade 1: ";
        cin >> grade1;
        cout << "Grade 2: ";
        cin >> grade2;
        cout << "Grade 3: ";
        cin >> grade3;
        cout << "Grade 4: ";
        cin >> grade4;
        cout << "Grade 5: ";
        cin >> grade5;
    }
};

void printAllStudents(student [], grades [], int);
void loadAllStudents(student [], grades [], int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    student theStudent[CLASSIZE];
    grades theGrade[CLASSIZE];

    loadAllStudents(theStudent, theGrade, CLASSIZE);
    printAllStudents(theStudent, theGrade, CLASSIZE);

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void loadAllStudents(student theStudents[], grades theGrades[], int s) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        theStudents[i].loadMe();
        theGrades[i].loadGrades();
    }
}
void printAllStudents(student theStudents[], grades theGrades[], int s) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        theStudents[i].printTheInfo(); 
        theGrades[i].printTheGrades();
    }
}
```

Comment: Retagged to remove "C".  This code uses C++ strings and streams and is incompatible with C.

Comment: Perhaps it would be pertinent to give an explicit question, such as "how should I proceed to implement <requirement of your choice> from here"?  Right now, we don't really know what you need help with.

Comment: Why do you declare `grade1` ... `grade5` ? An array `grade[5]` would be simpler...

Comment: Sorry, @BasileStarynkevitch how would I fix that?

Comment: @AndréCaron: That leads to your question, I would need to calculate the individual averages (minus lowest grade) for each student.

Comment: +1 for excellent code formatting.

Comment: But yeah, what's the exact question?

Comment: @SethCarnegie how can I correct the grade array, and use it to calculate individual averages?

Comment: You haven't said what is wrong with the grade array so I don't know how to correct it, but to calculate individual averages and show them, just add some code to `grades::PrintTheGrades` to add `grade1 + grade2 + ... + grade5` together and divide it by 5 to get the average, and display it. Also Basile is right, it would be easier to have an array of ints like `int allgrades[5]` instead of `int grade1; int grade2; ...` And that way you can use a loop to sum all the grades together.

Comment: Wow, I totally overlooked that. @SethCarnegie how could I combine the individual grades into an array grades[i]?

Comment: Here is an example: http://codepad.org/3fFXzDT7

Comment: @SethCarnegie Yes! That worked, thanks for the insight. Additionally, I assume it would be good practice to make a function in converting the average into a letter grade?

Comment: @Fusionice yes, if you're required to display a letter grade, a function would be appropriate.

Comment: @SethCarnegie If I make a function void letterGrade how would I correctly call this within struct grades

Comment: You should make a function with the signature `char letterGrade(double d)` and pass it the grade which is a double. `letterGrade` should return the character that represents the grade, and you just display it. For example, if you wanted to display the letter instead of the number, in my example you'd change `cout << endl << " Average: " << (average / NUMBER_OF_GRADES) << endl;` to `cout << endl << " Average: " << letterGrade(average / NUMBER_OF_GRADES) << endl;`

Comment: @SethCarnegie This is where the embarrasment comes.. I don't know how to declare letterGrade and how to pass the average to it

Comment: What part don't you know how? As for design, I would make it a `private` member function of `grades`, looking like `char letterGrade(double d) { ... }`

Comment: Got it working. I don't know what it is about functions that confuses me! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

First of all create an array of grades. You may use double for this:
double grade[5], instead of grade1, ..., grade5.
It is easier to calculate the average then.
While calculating the average for each student, you can store in a variable the current minimum value.